# Getting latest values from different columns based on other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I've a query like this

```
select 
  user_id,
  MAX(
    case when attribute = 'one' then newValue else 'No Update' end
  ) as one,
  MAX(
    case when attribute = 'two' then newValue else 'No Update' end
  ) as two,
  MAX(
    case when attribute = 'thre' then newValue else 'No Update' end
  ) as thre,
from table
group by user_id
```

This query returns result as max value for that particular attribute value in different column.

There is an `updated_at` column too in this table. Now instead of this, I want that the returned column should contain the latest value according to that updated_at field.

So basically the column `one, two and thre` should either contain latest values according to `updated_at` field. If no values are there, then the column should contain `No Update` string.

What could be the right way?

**Example**

```
user_id | attribute | newValue | updatedAt
1       | one       | null     | 2018-01-20
1       | one       | b        | 2018-01-21
1       | one       | a        | 2018-01-22
1       | two       | null     | 2018-01-23
1       | two       | null     | 2018-01-24
1       | two       | null     | 2018-01-25
```

So for above table the current query would return result as this coz `b` is the `Max` value for `attribute=one`

```
user_id | one | two 
    1   | b   | No Update
```

But I want the result of column `one` to be latest one according to `updatedAt` column like this

```
user_id | one | two 
    1   | a   | No Update
```

Comment: Show some example data and example desired results.

Comment: @MatBailie Updated. Let me know if the example is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres doesn't have first and last aggregation functions, but you can get similar functionality using arrays:

```
select user_id,
       coalesce((array_agg(newvalue order by updatedAt desc) filter (where attribute = 'one'))[1], 'No update') as one,
       coalesce((array_agg(newvalue order by updatedAt desc) filter (where attribute = 'two'))[1], 'No update') as two
from t 
group by user_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9a36bfba2a938c690a551088a33f022d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

First use `DISTINCT ON (user_id, attribute)` to get the only the rows with the latest `updatedAt` for each `attribute` and then aggregate on the results:

```
select user_id,
       coalesce(max(case when attribute = 'one' then newvalue end), 'No Update') one,
       coalesce(max(case when attribute = 'two' then newvalue end), 'No Update') two
from (
  select distinct on (user_id, attribute) *
  from tablename
  order by user_id, attribute, updatedAt desc
) t 
group by user_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=947879a6db533dc5390bda9fb5188de6).
Results:

```
> user_id | one | two      
> ------: | :-- | :--------
>       1 | a   | No Update
```